# MVC 5 Change ViewEngine Path Error: (must derive from ViewPage) even with WebConfig in View Root

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, web-config, razorengine

i try to move my Views default directory top a different path.

I have changed my Global.asax to add the directory in my view Engine like this

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        RegisterViewEngines(ViewEngines.Engines);
    }

    private static void RegisterViewEngines(ICollection<IViewEngine> engines)
    {
        engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine
        {
            //MasterLocationFormats = new[] { "~/App/Views/Admin/{0}.master" },
            PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Mvc/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.cshtml" },
            ViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Mvc/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml" }
        });
    }
```

This is the image of my new folder configuration

[image]

Every where i read i see that i need to add a web config to my Views root folder. So i take the one came in the template View and i paste it in my new folder configuration.

This is my /Mvc/Views/Web.Config

```html
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Template" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

No mater what i Always see this Error :

[image]
Error Stack Trace

> The view at '~/Mvc/Views/Login/Index.cshtml' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.
>
> Description : Une exception non gérée s'est produite au moment de l'exécution de la requête Web actuelle. Contrôlez la trace de la pile pour plus d'informations sur l'erreur et son origine dans le code.
>
> Détails de l'exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The view at '~/Mvc/Views/Login/Index.cshtml' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.

Comment: The view at '~/Mvc/Views/Login/Index.cshtml' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.

Answer (score 2):

I have found my solution, the problem was in my RegisterViewEngine Function.

I use the Class  WebFormViewEngine that is suppose to be used for file .ascx. for the Razor view you are suppose to use the Class RazorViewEngine

So i just have to change my function like this:

> ```
>     private static void RegisterViewEngines(ICollection<IViewEngine> engines)
>     {
>         engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine
>         {
>             //MasterLocationFormats = new[] { "~/App/Views/Admin/{0}.master" },
>             PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Mvc/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.cshtml" },
>             ViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Mvc/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml" }
>         });
>     }
> ```

Now it work perfectly!